# Error messages fuse with console in IDLE?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python (I've been messing with it for a few days), and anytime I have an error in my code, the message fuses into a giant mess of code; it's pretty hard to read and I can't actually go back and edit my code. Example:

```
import pygame
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame.init() {
    
SyntaxError: '{' was never closed
pygame.init()
(5, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))


======================================= RESTART: Shell =======================================
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
pygame.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    pygame.init()
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
import pygame
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame.init()
(5, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    
SyntaxError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 3
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()

    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 5, in <module>
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

The code looks awful and I can't separate *anything*. I've looked through all the preferences and settings for the app, and I hope there's at least an extension to fix this mess; any ideas?

P.S. --I'm on a Mac

Comment: You shouldn't be typing large amounts of code in the shell window.  Open an editor window, and write your code there; the errors will appear in the shell, without affecting your code.

Comment: TBH it's probably time to upgrade from IDLE to a more robust IDE. Typically when you write code, you write your script in an editor and then run the script in a separate terminal. IDLE is really just for your very beginner 'hello world' scripts.

Comment: C_Z_, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're typing your code in the interactive console window. While I find it useful to try simple code snippets out, anything more complex than a few lines of code should be run from disk.

In order to use IDLE properly:

- Press `File` -> `New File` or push `Ctrl+N`.
- Type your code.
- Press `File` -> `Save As..` or push `Ctrl+Shift+S` and save your file to disk.
- Press `Run` - `Run Module` or push `F5` to run your code. You should see the output (if there is any) in the interactive console window.